# Crontab run MongoDB script in javascript file

Tags: javascript, mongodb, cron

I tried this :

```
0 0 */15 * * /usr/bin/mongo stories  /usr/share/cronjobs/15days.js
* * * * * touch /usr/share/neargood/testing.txt
```

The testing.txt file is  effectively created each minute, but the mongo script doesn't have any effect.
15days.js :

```
d=new Date();
mdate15 = new Date(d.getUTCFullYear(),d.getUTCMonth(),d.getUTCDate()-15);
db.story.update({ date: {$lte:mdate15} , active:1},{ $set: {active:0}},{ multi: true })
```

What could the problem be ?

Comment: Manually it works. When I run Cron the Email I get is : 
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.8
connecting to: stories

Comment: I changed the js file to executable , IT worked :) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens when you run the command by hand? Does it work? If so, it could be a permissions issue. Check all files involved to make sure that the cron user has privilege to read and/or execute where applicable.

If it runs manually, then I'd guess it's got something to do with how things are chmod'd and/or chown'd. Find out what user cron runs as, and check to see if the mongo binary can be run by it. Also, check the permissions and ownership of 15days.js